# Add UITableView inside UITableViewCell with automatic height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display UITableView inside a UITableViewCell. The table view inside the table view cell may have a random count of the cell so the cell height should be table view content size height

I added constraints and here is my height for a row at index path

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: add some additional code

Comment: Hi @Anbu.Karthik You are expecting which part of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `InnerCellModel` make a method.

```
-(CGFloat)cellHeight {
    CGFloat height = [self makeSomeMethodToCalculateHeightOfText:self.title withFont: yourLabelFont, andWidth: yourLabelWidth];
    height += someMarginIfAvailable;
    return height;
}
```

then iterate your array and add height of each index in a single variable and then assign it to your `innerTableViewHeightConstraint`.

Set some Height Constraint to your inner `UITableView` and then in the `cellForRowAt indexPath` after `[innerTableView reload]` and then set

```
innerTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = innerTableView.contentSize.height;
// Or You can even calculate your inner height and then set it to your tableView.
innerTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = numberOfCells * innerCellHeight;
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

> P.S: Your Cell height must be UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
>   Inner TableView Must have Top, Left, Right, Bottom and Height Constraints as well.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Content Size will not give you accurate solution. You have to calculate TableView height by multiplying numberOfCells to Each cell height.

Comment: Actually the subcells also dynamic height

Comment: Then you have to calculate each cells height with respect to their content and then assign it to your tableView.

Comment: Ok that wil be fine

Comment: I have update my answer you may get a way to handle this situation.